# Redis (via GCP Memorystore) is out of memory although maxmemory-policy is allkeys-lru

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, redis, google-cloud-memorystore

In a GCP App Engine application using Redis (6.x) as Memorystore, with a `maxmemory-policy` configured as `allkeys-lru`, we get out of memory errors.

Furthermore, every key that we write to Redis has a TTL of 2 hours.   In spite of this, the memory usage graph is steadily growing (with occasionnal troughs), until it hits the maximum memory.  When it does, it seems the LRU policy is not able to reclaim memory and all calls to Redis end up in "out of memory" errors.

It seems to me that reclaiming memory with an LRU policy is the core feature of a cache server, and I cannot imagine Redis would have an actual bug there.  So is there some other configuration options that we should look into.  Of all the `maxmemory-policy options`, `allkeys-lru` seems to be the most appropriate, for use as a database access cache.

Comment: The documentation (https://redis.io/docs/reference/eviction/) says "So we continuously cross the boundaries of the memory limit, by going over it, and then by evicting keys to return back under the limits."   Could it be that this "common" crossing of boundary is simply not compatible with the way GCP handles the memory limit ?

Comment: Check the link for [helpful document](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/memory-management-best-practices#resolving_an_out_of_memory_condition)  to prevent the out of memory condition.Also check the [best practices recommended to manage the memorystore](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/memory-management-best-practices).

Comment: Post a screenshot of all your redis settings.  Redis is working fine with my GAE app.

Answer (score 1):

The explanation is that GCP Memorystore allocates a fixed memory size of say 1GB, and by default it also sets the maxmemory of Redis to the same amount.
But the way Redis handles the limit is by going past it. Quoting from the documentation (https://redis.io/docs/reference/eviction/) *"We continuously cross the boundaries of the memory limit, by going over it, and then by evicting keys to return back under the limits"*.  But GCP gives no leeway, so crossing the limit is not an option, so it fails with an out of memory error.

The solution is to allways set `maxmemory-percent=95` on your Memorystore configuration, which means that the LRU reclaiming actions are trigered when reaching 95% of the maximum, not 100%.  Of course the appropriate value may be some other value, but 95% seems ok as a first guess.

This should definitely be a default setting when a project creates a Memorystore with Redis.

Comment: The fact that the memory usage kept growing in spite of a TTL is a different issue, the TTL was not set properly.  This caused the usage to grow, but it is not what caused the out of memory error when the limit is reached.